# Express.js: Convert req.body into POST encoded string

Tags: javascript, http, post, node.js, express

I'm using the express.bodyParser middleware and I'm trying to convert req.body object into a POST encoded string. Is there a way of doing this?

Example:

```
Name: Jonathan Doe
Age: 23
Formula: a + b == 13%!
```

Becomes:

```
Name=Jonathan+Doe&Age=23&Formula=a+%2B+b+%3D%3D+13%25%21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node has a module for this.

```
var qs = require('querystring');
...
console.log(qs.stringify(req.body));
```

But connect/express store the raw body in `req.rawBody` anyway.

Comment: `req.rawBody` is returing `undefined`

Comment: @TarandeepGill, see this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710225/node-js-get-raw-request-body-using-express

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be fairly simple - you should be able to do it the same way you would do in a browser. This function converts all string/number members of an object/array to a string that can be used as a POST body:

```
var objectToPostBody = function (object) {
  var i, out;
  if (!object) {
    return false;
  }
  out = [];
  for (i in object) {
    if (typeof object[i] === 'string' || typeof object[i] === 'number') {
      out[out.length] = encodeURIComponent(i) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(object[i]);
    }
  }
  return out.join('&');
};
```

If you want to handle sub-arrays/sub-objects the function would get more complicated, but for what you describe above I think that should do the trick.