# View RawBody In SailsJS

Tags: json, sails.js

I'd like to dump out, via sails.log.debug(), the raw POSTed data as seen by a controller function. I am dealing with JSON coming from a third-party that may be badly formatted and need to figure out where/how. I'd like to see the whole, raw dump.

```
create: function(req, res) {
  sails.log.debug(???);
  //var ticket = JSON.parse(req.param("webhook"));

  return res.echoRequest(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use middleware to get the "RAW" body. You will want to grab that pre-sails 
Check out answer to this question [Node.js - get raw request body using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710225/node-js-get-raw-request-body-using-express)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var packet = req.params.all();
sails.log.debug(packet);
```

Hope that helps.