# Why use body-parser module in node.js?

Tags: node.js, parsing, body-parser

I Am using the MEAN stack to develop an application following some video tutorials
in the video he use the **body-parser**  node.js module  in the server side   I want to understand why :
does it convert **application/json** HTTP requests to a **JSON object**? so **node.js** can use **JSON format** to work on the Request ?

Answer (score 0):

by pure `express` you have only request headers and body as set of strings

but you want to work with set of parameters and values for doing backend jobs

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

it's allow you to `parse` request body into `Object` with {param: 'value'} structure, and deal with arrays and other complex structures inside body data

the name of library pretty self-explaining -> `Parsing body data`
You can do it by yourself from scratch, but then you write another `body-parser`

at the github docs you'll see all supported content-types

Comment: thank you for your response.

so basically it enable me to convert a HTTP request from a **string** to **JSON object**  to enable me to acces later on to a different elements inn the HTTP request using JSON notations for example req.body access to the body. and without it I'll have to deal with a stringify HTTP request. .
Am I right ? and please is there any tool that i can use to see the stringify version of the request ? (firebug  and Chrome console doesn't display it)

Comment: You can use `Charles` on OS X and `Fiddler` on Windows, shows you raw http packets. To get raw body from node.js try to look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710225/node-js-get-raw-request-body-using-express