# Can't find data/payload from Shopify Webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, webhooks

## Summary

I have been following the Shopify tutorial on setting up an App using Node and React. I have everything working but I am trying to move past the last step. I am trying to get the data returned from the Shopify webhooks and I can't see where the data/payload is.

## Background

I've tried printing out the response and request both before and after the middleware but didn't seem to get anything useful back, just recieved things like the following:

```
{ method: 'POST',
  url: '/webhooks/products/create',
  header:
   { host: '01e9702c.ngrok.io',
     'user-agent': 'Shopify-Captain-Hook',
     'content-length': '1175',
     accept: '*/*',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     'x-shopify-api-version': '2019-07',
     'x-shopify-hmac-sha256': 'some value',
     'x-shopify-product-id': '2018829729858',
     'x-shopify-shop-domain': 'example.myshopify.com',
     'x-shopify-topic': 'products/create',
     connection: 'close',
     'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
     'x-forwarded-for': '123.456.789' } }
```

```
  router.post('/webhooks/products/create', webhook, (ctx) => {
    console.log('Products webhook - create: ', ctx.state.webhook);
    // Want to view product that was created here
  });

  router.post('/webhooks/products/delete', webhook, (ctx, x) => {
    console.log('Products webhook - delete: ', ctx.state.webhook);
    // Want to see product that was deleted here
  });
```

## Expected Output

I would expect to receive a json object as described in the Shopify Webhook event docs. e.g.

```
{
  "id": 788032119674292922,
  "title": "Example T-Shirt",
  "body_html": null,
  "vendor": "Acme",
  "product_type": "Shirts",
  "created_at": null,
  "handle": "example-t-shirt",
  "updated_at": null,
  "published_at": "2019-08-08T16:16:49-04:00",
  "template_suffix": null,
  "tags": "mens t-shirt example",
  "published_scope": "web",
  "variants": [
    {
      "id": 642667041472713922,
      "product_id": 788032119674292922,
      "title": "",
      "price": "19.99",
      "sku": "example-shirt-s",
      "position": 0,
      "inventory_policy": "deny",
      "compare_at_price": "24.99",
      "fulfillment_service": "manual",
      "inventory_management": "shopify",
      "option1": "Small",
      "option2": null,
      "option3": null,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "taxable": true,
      "barcode": null,
      "grams": 200,
      "image_id": null,
      "weight": 200.0,
      "weight_unit": "g",
      "inventory_item_id": null,
      "inventory_quantity": 75,
      "old_inventory_quantity": 75,
      "requires_shipping": true
    },
    {
      "id": 757650484644203962,
      "product_id": 788032119674292922,
      "title": "",
      "price": "19.99",
      "sku": "example-shirt-m",
      "position": 0,
      "inventory_policy": "deny",
      "compare_at_price": "24.99",
      "fulfillment_service": "manual",
      "inventory_management": "shopify",
      "option1": "Medium",
      "option2": null,
      "option3": null,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "taxable": true,
      "barcode": null,
      "grams": 200,
      "image_id": null,
      "weight": 200.0,
      "weight_unit": "g",
      "inventory_item_id": null,
      "inventory_quantity": 50,
      "old_inventory_quantity": 50,
      "requires_shipping": true
    }
  ],
  "options": [
    {
      "id": 527050010214937811,
      "product_id": 788032119674292922,
      "name": "Title",
      "position": 1,
      "values": [
        "Small",
        "Medium"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "id": 539438707724640965,
      "product_id": 788032119674292922,
      "position": 0,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "alt": null,
      "width": 323,
      "height": 434,
      "src": "\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/assets\/shopify_shirt-39bb555874ecaeed0a1170417d58bbcf792f7ceb56acfe758384f788710ba635.png",
      "variant_ids": [
      ]
    }
  ],
  "image": null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the web framework you are using? Is it Express? Adding the code for webhook would help but right now your signatures are off.

See my answer here [Nodejs - Expressjs - Verify shopify webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745204/nodejs-expressjs-verify-shopify-webhook) for how to use the verify method of body parser.

Then your hook handler would look like:

```
router.post('/webhooks/products/create', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, ' '));
    res.sendStatus(200);
    // process the webhook
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Koa framework from the basic node/react example.

Assuming you have already found it, but anyone looking, the answer is `ctx.state.webhook.payload`
You can acces the individual elements from there so
`ctx.state.webhook.payload.title` etc also work.