# Verify Facebook X-Hub-Signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, parse-platform, webhooks

On Cloud Code on Parse Im trying to verify the header *x-hub-signature* received from Facebook webhook.

`secret` is the right secret-key of the Facebook app.

```
var
hmac,
expectedSignature,
payload = JSON.stringify(req.body),
secret = 'xyzxyzxyz';

hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret);
hmac.update(payload, 'utf-8');
expectedSignature = 'sha1=' + hmac.digest('hex');
console.log(expectedSignature);
console.log(req.headers['x-hub-signature']);
```

but the signatures never match.
What is wrong?

Comment: What’s the actual contant of `payload`, after you used JSON.stringify?

Comment: the string representation of the JSON received in the body, starting with {"entry":[{"changes":[.......

Answer (score 6):

Your `bodyParserJSON` should return **rawBody**:

```
bodyParser.json({
    verify(req, res, buf) {
      req.rawBody = buf;
    },
})
```

Here is a middleware that I've written. It uses `crypto` module to generate `sha1`

```
fbWebhookAuth: (req, res, next) => {
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', process.env.FB_APP_SECRET);
    // hmac.update(req.rawBody, 'utf-8'); //older versions
    hmac.update(req.rawBody, 'utf8');
    if (req.headers['x-hub-signature'] === `sha1=${hmac.digest('hex')}`) next();
    else res.status(400).send('Invalid signature');
}
```

and finally in your route you can use it as:

```
app.post('/webhook/facebook', middlewares.fbWebhookAuth, facebook.webhook);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're parsing the body into an object with middleware, check out [Node.js - get raw request body using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710225/node-js-get-raw-request-body-using-express)

If you're already using the raw parsing module, it should work if you don't `JSON.stringify` req.body:

```
payload = req.body,
```