# How to see the content stored in a path?

Tags: node.js, http, express, postman

I wrote the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

app.put('/data', function(req, res) {
    res.send("OK");
});

app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    console.log();  // What to write here?
});
app.listen(4000);
```

I sent a PUT request by Postman:
[image]

Now, I want to ask what I to write inside the brackets of console.log that the code will print the content stored in the http path?

I want to see the JSON

> {"name":"John"}

**EDIT:** I tried the solution shown in this link: 
[Node.js - get raw request body using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710225/node-js-get-raw-request-body-using-express):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.rawBody = '';
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        req.rawBody += chunk;
    });
    next();
});
app.use(bodyParser());

app.put('/data', function(req, res) {
    res.send("OK");
});

app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    console.log(res.rawBody);
    res.end();
});

app.listen(4000);
```

I still didn't get what I expected.

Comment: Your first screenshot looks like you are already doing a PUT from postman. Maybe it's an issue with your server instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - get raw request body using Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710225/node-js-get-raw-request-body-using-express)

Comment: @Quentin, I tried it and it didn't work out.