# Post blob image file to express server with javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

**App.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

**Background**

I am currently rendering a `C3.js` chart in a webpage. I need to have the image representation of that chart so I can display it in other ways throughout my app. In order to do that I am converting the `SVG` to `canvas` with `html2canvas` and then converting that to a `blob` which I then post to an express server.

When I check the network tab I can see the `blob` is in the `payload` section. But, on the server when I `console.log(req.body)` it outputs an empty `object {}`.

**Example**

*Client Side*

```
function setImage() {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector('#chart')).then(canvas => {
    canvas.toBlob(
      function(blob) {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/pdf';

        fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {},
          body: blob,
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(success => console.log(success))
          .catch(error => console.log(error));

        console.log(blob);
      },
      'image/jpeg',
      1,
    );
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  });
}
```

*Server Side*

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  res.json({ message: 'Something good happened' });
});
```

**Things I have tried**

```
JSON.stringify(blob)
```

Different headers but I also read that leaving it blank should also work,

```
headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
```

*In the network tab from chrome dev tools*

[image]

*The terminal output from the express route*

[image]

When I `console.log(blob)` it looks like an object,

[image]
**Question**

What is the proper way to POST the blob and verify that I have access to it on the server?

Comment: [req.body Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) — Your code is missing any sign of a middleware parser. Do you have one? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: usually string should be fine for body, but try to wrap it in JSON like: `body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })`

Comment: @DomenikReitzner — A [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) is not a string.

Comment: @wuno — It is an issue with body parser. Presumably, none of the other routes are trying to process a raw file. See the duplicate question.

Comment: Anyone else stumbling here can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710225/node-js-get-raw-request-body-using-express?noredirect=1&lq=1